# To draw several histogram in a temporal axis

Tags: graphics, histograms, charts

I have 1000 histograms obtained from a Monte-Carlo complex simulation process. So to explain what I am searching I will simplify my problem.

If I  want to draw 3 histograms on the same scale, I will write a program like the following one

```
h1 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 1000];
h2 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, .2], 1000];
h3 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, .3], 1000];
Histogram[{h1, h2, h3}]
```

which will gives

[image]

But, this graphic is not easy to read and there is a third temporal axis, since all distributions are obtained step after step. So I would add a  third axis and draw the histogram obliquely with the 0 of the two others axes situated on the third one, as is the usage for stochastic processes.

Thanks for the help

Comment: If you have lots of "data" (which by definition one gets with Monte Carlo simulations), you want to abandon the use of histograms and use nonparametric density estimates which can be constructed in *Mathematica* using `SmoothKernelDistribution`.  This approach is especially better than histograms when you want to show multiple curves.  And you can produce the third axis easily.  3D "smoothed histograms" are also available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To emphasize my comment:  when one wants to display many histograms, one really needs to use nonparametric density estimators.  Here's an example:

```
nSimulations = 25;
nSamples = 1000;  (* Sample size for each pdf *)
n = 1000;  (* Number of points for drawing each pdf *)
pdfs = ConstantArray[0, {nSimulations, n}];
μ = Table[-1. + 4 (i - 1)/(nSimulations - 1), {i, nSimulations}];
σ = Table[1. - 0.8 (i - 1)/(nSimulations - 1), {i, nSimulations}];
Do[h = SmoothKernelDistribution[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[μ[[i]], σ[[i]]], nSamples]];
 pdfs[[i]] = Table[{i, x, PDF[h, x]}, {x, -5, 5, 10/n}],
 {i, nSimulations}]

ListPointPlot3D[pdfs, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Black]
```

[image: Multiple smooth kernel distributions in 3D]

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use `Histogram3D`:

```
Histogram3D[{Transpose@{ConstantArray[1, Length[h1]], h1}, 
  Transpose@{ConstantArray[2, Length[h2]], h2}, 
  Transpose@{ConstantArray[3, Length[h3]], h3}}]
```

[image]

More generally, if you place all your data in a big matrix:

```
h = {h1, h2, h3}; 
Histogram3D[Transpose[{ConstantArray[#, Length[h[[#]]]], h[[#]]}] & /@ Range[3]]
```

then you can plot all 1000 data sets just by changing the parameter in the `Range` function.